# Ant Design Form.List converting circular structure to JSON problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, ant-design-pro

I have an error after converting all form data to JSON.
`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'Window' --- property 'window' closes the circle at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)`

Here a piece of code ->

```
const Component = () => {
   const navigate = useNavigate();
   const [form] = Form.useForm();
   const [initialValues] = useState(getFormData());
   const [percent, setPercent] = useState<number>(0);
   const onFinish = useCallback(
     (values) => {
       console.log(values);
       setFormData(values);
       navigate(ROUTES.CREATE_PERSONA, { state: { activeStep: 1 } });
     },
     [navigate],
   );
   return (
      <Form
        form={form}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        className={styles.form}
      >
         <InputWrapper title='Responsibilities'>
            <Form.List name='responsibilities'>
              {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
                <Space size={16} direction='vertical' style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                  {fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }) => (
                    <div key={key} className={styles['form-text-area-wrapper']}>
                      <span className={styles['form-text-area-dot']} />
                      <Form.Item
                        name={`responsibility-${key}`}
                        key={key}
                        {...restField}
                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                      >
                        <TextArea
                          className={styles['form-text-area']}
                          maxLength={500}
                          autoSize={{ minRows: 2, maxRows: 5 }}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                      <span
                        className={styles['form-text-area-delete']}
                        onClick={() => remove(name)}
                        aria-hidden
                      >
                        <UrnIcon />
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                  <Form.Item>
                    <Button ghost onClick={add} className={styles['form-text-area-add']}>
                      <span />
                      <Typography className={styles['form-text-area-add-title']}>
                        Add responsibility
                      </Typography>
                    </Button>
                  </Form.Item>
                </Space>
              )}
            </Form.List>
          </InputWrapper>
      </Form>
)
}
```

Here is the result after submit button is pressed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m03hg.png)

I don't understand why my result form data added this "SyntheticBaseEvent"?
How to delete this line or make it so this field is not added to the form result?

Comment: Change `onClick={add}` to `onClick={()=>add()}`. This will fix the problem.

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique Its works. Thx man, my bad, its my carelessness(